# Populating array list via main method console IO

Tags: java, arrays, io, switch-statement, bluej

I'm brand new to programming and taking my baby steps with BlueJ. The problem I'm having is this - As part of coursework, I have been tasked with writing a simple program for an Earthquake Monitoring system. I have created and compiled the necessary classes and have set up my Main Method in the I/O console. I have created a menu but I'm stuck at how to get from the menu selection, to the array lists containing the fields to input and record the required data? Here is what I've got in the main monitor I/O so far. Apologies if this a bit clumsy and I'm crashing about like an oaf. Thanks in advance!

```
public class mainMonitorIO {
    /**
     * The starting point for the earthquake monitoring program.
     */
    static Scanner key = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {int choice = 0;
        while (choice!=6){System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("* Enter one of the following commands");


        System.out.println("* Option 1) Add new Observatory");


        System.out.println("* Option 2) Add new Earthquake");


        System.out.println ("* Option 3) Get largest magnitude");


        System.out.println ("* Option 4) Get largest average");


        System.out.println ("* Option 5) Get all earthquakes (over given number)");


        System.out.println ("* Optiom 6) Exit");


        System.out.println ("********************************************************");



        choice = key.nextInt();

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            System.out.println ("Input New Observatory Data");
            break;
            case 2:
            System.out.println ("Input New Earthquake Data");
            break;
            case 3:
            System.out.println ("Return Largest Magnitude");
            break;
            case 4:
            System.out.println ("Reurn Largest Average");
            break;
            case 5:
            System.out.println ("Return all Earthquakes over given magnitude");
            break;
            case 6:
            System.out.println ("You have chosen to exit, Goodbye!");
            break;               
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);      
}
```

Comment: Which `ArrayList`s are you trying to access? I don't see any in your code.

Comment: I have four classes.
1) Earthquake
2) Observatory (contains arraylist of earthquakes)
3) Monitor (contains arraylist of observatory
and finally
4) Monitor Main IO
I have got the menu but can't work out how to connect the choice from the menu selection to add new observatory, new earthquake etc. Do I need to bring the relevant array lists into the Main IO then?